# Employee performance- working on personal business while being paid by employer

Tags: performance, moonlighting

I have an employee who has started a Soccer Golf League in our area.  His quality, quantity, and timeliness have taken a nose dive.   I am certain that he is working on his start up company while submitting timesheets and getting paid by me. While I am certain, I have no proof.   How should I handle?

Answer (score 8):

If his performance has gone down, you should have a talk with him about the fact that it is happening, about the fact that you are not happy about it, whether there are good (acceptable) reasons for the performance drop, and whether there are things that you could do and that he could do to improve the performance.

You could then mention that dropped performance because of work on company time that benefits him but not the company is *not* acceptable and if found out would lead to instant dismissal.

If his dropped performance isn't good enough in your opinion for you to keep him employed and to pay his salary, then you should mention that as well. And if you are willing to look for a replacement, that is a fact worth mentioning.

Comment: I like that your answer does not include mentioning the employee's Soccer Golf League specifically. Since OP doesn't have proof that the league is a factor in the performance drop, best not to bring it up by name, but this opens the door for the employee to volunteer it.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the problem and its solution, not any unsubstantiated suspicions about the cause.  It is even possible that the employee doesn't realize that his performance has dropped.  Either way, he should be given the chance to improve.

Answer (score 4):

> How should I handle?

Concentrate on his performance on the job, and not why it nosedived. You have suspicions, but you don't really know the "why". And either way, the "why" is not your problem, it's the employee's problem.

If you are the employer, in general you don't care why an employee's performance has drastically changed for the worse, only that it has, and only that it turn around.

Have a talk with this employee. Indicate what you have observed. Indicate that this negative change cannot continue. Indicate the consequences that could arise if this doesn't change now.

Let the employee decide for himself why it has happened, and what he needs to do to reverse the trend if he wants to continue to be employed.

As the employer, you need to hold employees responsible for their performance. Employees need to decide what is important to themselves.